# [Possible Duplicate]: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I know there are lot of questions and answers are available like this but since 2 days I tried to figure out this issue and not got any success.

I have added the below listed frameworks in my projects,

libSqlite3.dylib
    AddressBook.framework
    AssetsLibrary.framework
    AVFoundation.framework
    CoreMotion.framework
    MediaPlayer.framework

but not getting any success

[image][image]

Comment: have u integrated Google Plus ? Seems that some frame work is missing or the google plus framework is not added properly,

Comment: Yes there is GooglePlus framework integration but to fix this issue I have removed and added GooglePlus SDK and other related frameworks many times but getting the same result as mentioned above.

Comment: may be the below link help u out

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3106

Comment: @Purva: Checked but not got the success.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've copied the Frameworks into your project, rather than just linking to them, so they only contain the library compiled for device. Xcode will normally locate the Simulator version of the framework for you.

Delete any of the .framework folders in your project and Finder, then follow Step 6 of this tutorial with the frameworks you listed in your original post: http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework#Framework

Comment: Thanks, this tip helped me to get out and the solution is add all frameworks mentioned in above answer.

Answer (score 2):

This library AssetsLibrary.framework in Step 3, is not included in your project, that's why you are getting this error.

Try these:

You need to add the AssetsLibrary framework to the “Link Binary With Libraries” build phase of your target.

Try cleaning your project using Command+Shift+K and adding the required frameworks again. Hope it will start working

Copy files into your project but forgot to check the target to add the files to. To resolve: Open the Build Phases for the correct target, expand Compile Sources and add the missing .m files.

Another cause, may be:

You include a static library that is built for another architecture like i386, the simulator on your host machine. To resolve:
If you have multiple library files from your libraries vendor to include in the project you need to include the one for the simulator (i386) and the one for the device (armv7 for example).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but same answer I read on the stack overflow and tried the steps also I mentioned in the question itself that I have added the listed frameworks in the projects.

Comment: up 1 for nice description.

Answer (score 0):

Missing library or missing .m file

Check and add:
TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add your .m class -> Build and Run